# Random spaces with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf, text-extraction

I wrote a program and used PyPDF2 to extract text from a pdf file, but sometimes and only with some files it reads something out like
E ff e c t
When the word is Effect and it is not a few words, it is in the whole document.
Does anybody have a solution to this or a recommendation for another package to use?

I used a file and there it didnt set the extra spaces, but when i thought i was done and used another file it just added random spaces without editing the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [what are you asking], and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and provide a [mre].

Comment: Try `pdfminer.six` - https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/highlevel.html